# What useful minor features of C# 4.0 can you list?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

C# 4.0 has a lot of new major features such as dynamic type, covariance and contravariance, named arguments etc.

But C# 4.0 contains new minor (but useful) changes such as `TryParse` method for `TimeSpan, Enum, Guid` data types, `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, `System.IO.Stream.CopyTo` etc.

What other *minor* and *useful* features of C# 4.0 can you list?

Comment: Make this community wiki and this question just might avoid being closed and you might not get downvoted to oblivion.

Answer (score 2):

You need to differentiate between features of the language vs features of the framework. For C#4.0, those features you list are the new features that was added.

For .NET Framework 4, the list is long. Some of the most interesting and/or generally usable ones include:

- [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx)
- [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) and [Complex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex(v=VS.100).aspx) types.
- [Lazy<T>](http://Lazy<T>)
- [ASP .NET improvements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s57a598e(v=VS.100).aspx)
- [Better support for parallel computing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693(v=VS.100).aspx), including the new [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks(v=VS.100).aspx) namespace ("lightweight" threads) and Parallel LINQ.

There is an [exhaustive list here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868(v=VS.100).aspx). It is also interesting to read the [list of obsoleted types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461503(v=VS.100).aspx) in the new version.